# Position: Sticky does not seem to work if it is a child node inside of a wrapper

Tags: css, position, css-position, sticky

I'm working on trying to get `position: sticky` working for an element that is inside of another wrapper.

Here is an example codepen where it is not working (make sure the bottom area is small enough to be scrollable.)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWLrXd

(Notice all `dt` stick, but not he one wrapped in the `div class='broken'` tag.)

Any thoughts on why this may be happening?

EDIT:
I've noticed that if I set the display for the wrapper to `inline`, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that if I set the display property for the wrapper to `inline`, it works!

No clue why.